# Get String from Substring at a particular range

Tags: swift, string, substring

I want to write a function where I check the last 3 characters of a string are a part of another string or not, if it does I simply return true, else false.

Example :-

```
let str1 = "abc"
let str2 = "HiaBC"
```

What I want to check here is if str1 exists in last characters of str2, irrespective of case sensitiveness.

I tried

```
str2.contains("HI") // returned true as abc existed, should have returned false as it was not in the last 3 characters of the string.

func checkSubstring(str1:String, str2:String) -> Bool {
    if str2.contains(str1) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

What I wanted was to somehow apply some range and check if last 3 characters are present in a substring or not.

Anyone can suggest anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `range(of:)` with the appropriate options:

- `.caseInsensitive` for case insensitive search,
- `.backwards` to start the search from the end of the string, and
- `.anchored` to limit the search to the end of the source string.

```
func checkSubstring(str1:String, str2:String) -> Bool {
    return str2.range(of: str1, options: [.caseInsensitive, .backwards, .anchored]) != nil
}
```

Example:

```
print(checkSubstring(str1: "abc", str2: "HiaBC")) // true
print(checkSubstring(str1: "ab", str2: "HiaBC")) // false
```

Comment: Just a note that this requires Foundation to be imported.

Comment: Also, this seems to give false positives for corner cases like "aße" and "asse".

Comment: @Cristik: `"ß".caseInsensitiveCompare("ss") == .orderedSame` also returns `true` – probably because both `"ß".uppercased()` and `"ss".uppercased()` are equal to "SS".

Comment: That could be the reason, but on the other hand  Vadian's code seems to work for this particular case :)

Comment: @Cristik: That is more a side effect of his use of `suffix()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is `suffix(3)` to consider only the last three characters and `caseInsensitiveCompare` which is self-explanatory.

```
func checkSubstring(str1: String, str2: String) -> Bool {
    return str2.suffix(3).caseInsensitiveCompare(str1) == .orderedSame
}
```

Comment: Just a note that this requires Foundation to be imported.